# How do you modify blending options with a photoshop script?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, javascript, photoshop-cs4

I have a Photoshop Javascript script that cycles through different layers and I want to give a different outer glow to each layer based on the name of the layer.

Can someone give an example on how to change the blending options of an ArtLayer class programatically?